# Semantics: Dominant predictor?

Tags: predictor

This is more of a semantic question that I am not really sure about.

So let's say I have developed a logistic model, and I have done some bootstrapping/cross-validation on it. From the method I have used for development, one candidate predictor have a high selection frequency from all bootstrapped/cross-validated models. For example it appears in 98% of all models, and the coefficient of the predictor are high, i.e. it has a high impact on the log-odds of the model.

What is the correct term for a predictor like this ? Is dominant predictor the right word, or are there a true statistical way of referring to "dominant" predictors ?